# python: how to return two values at different position of calculating in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, yield

I want to have a function that process the data in the predefined pipeline, and I need the data at intermediate and final step, so I want to have a function that I can call twice, in the first call, the function returns the intermediate data, and in the second call, the function starts from the last return position and returns the final data, so something like this:

```
def tworeturns(x):
    intermediate = do-something(x)
    return intermediate
    final = do-something(intermediate)
    return final
```

How to implement this with python?

==========================================================================

Thanks to new-dev-123's answer I was able to return two values, but then I got another problem. After the first yield, I changed the intermediate, and when I call the next for the second time, I want the function to compute based on the modified intermediate, not the original intermediate. Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: try: return intermediate , final

Comment: I think you want a coroutine - try using `yield` instead of return and driving the coroutine from your caller using `next(tworeturns(x))`

Comment: If you need the outputs at different times then you're out of luck. You could try a generator, if the `do-something` requires a 'state'. Otherwise maybe there's a way you can rewrite the function (or split it) so that it's agnostic.

Comment: no I want them to be returned asynchronally. because I need intermediate to decide how to compute the final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generator like a coroutine allows you to effectively pause the function and you can drive it using `next()`

```
>>> def tworeturns(x):
...     print(f"hi {x}")
...     yield
...     print(f"bye {x}")
...     yield
... 
>>> corou = tworeturns("bob")
>>> next(corou)
hi bob
>>> next(corou)
bye bob
```

here's a quick demo I did on cli

So for your example you would do something like:

```
def tworeturns(x):
    intermediate = do-something(x)
    yield intermediate
    final = do-something(intermediate)
    yield final

corou = tworeturns(x)
first_value = next(corou)
second_value = next(corou)
```

Comment: here's a new problem, after the first  yield, I changed the intermediate, now when I call next, the function continues with the original intermediate. Is there a way to continue the computation with the modified intermediate value?

Comment: You'll have to paste the code since I can't replicate what you're saying. It should be using the modified values already.

Answer (score 2):

OK, that's a nice question, I sometimes have similar situations.

As one of the comments to your question says, you can use a generator, which literally answers your question.

But I like better the following solution:

```
def tworeturns(x, intermediate=None):
    if intermediate is None:
        return do_something(x)
    else:
        return do_something(intermediate)
```

Of course, you will now need to call `tworeturns` with the intermediate result. But it's a clear code, and also, stateless.

Answer (score 0):

Return both values(which will give you a tuple):

```
def tworeturns(x):
    intermediate = do-something(x)
    final = do-something(intermediate)
    return intermediate, final
```